# Unix, Shell Scripting

Tags: unix, shell-script, carriage-return

I am extracting data from an Oracle database and writing it into a flat file. I need the line delimiter to be FFLF. I am able to add the FF character but I am unable to remove the CR character. How can I remove the CR charater

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you can do this, but how about

```
tr -d "\r" < input.file > output.file
```

"tr" translates characters - in this case we use the -d switch to delete rather then replace characters, and then specify to delete the "cr" character. As tr operates using stdin and stdout, we use redirections to efficiently create a file with the new data.